# pgpool connect failed: No such file /tmp.s.PGSQL.0 replication mode = true

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

Setup: I have two instances of Postgres 9.0.3 and pg_pool 3.14 all running on the same Ibuntu (10.04) machine and am attempting to evaluate pgpool.

I can attach to pgpool using `psql -p <pgpool port>` but only when the `pgpool.conf` file has replication mode = false. If I set the replication mode = true then I see the log file generate the connection failure error on `/tmp.s.PGSQL.0` when I attempt the psql connection to pgpool's port.

After more exploration I would note that the additional error messages in the log indicate a failover handler is called, starting degeneration and shutdown secondary host(0) ????

After this if I do not restart pgool I can successfully connect (with replication mode = true) but I do not see any load sharing of my selects between my servers. (I have the load_share variable also set to true.)

What I am attempting to do is have have my insert/update statements replicated across my pool of servers and my selects to be load shared. Seem to be following the suggested setup but I encounter the above error problem.

Comments?

Comment: This is perhaps a simple cockpit error.  I installed pgpool 3.4.1 and should have installed pgpool II 3.1

Answer (score 1):

AS per my comment this ended up being a misunderstanding between pgppool and pgpool-II being separate open source projects.  When correctly using pgpoolII and it's documentation this error was not a problem.